# Passing a function as a parameter that will be an onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that returns a `React.ReactElement` obejct.  I want to pass that function a function that is assigned to an `onClick` button event.

I call the function:

```
this._createInjurySection1Drawer([{innerDrawer: this._createInjurySection2Drawer, shouldShow:this._OnClickCloseInjurySection2}])
```

The function:

```
private _createInjurySection1Drawer(innerDrawers: any[]): React.ReactNode {

    ...

    let innerDrawer;
    let shouldShow;

    console.log("_createInjurySection1Drawer | innerDrawers: ", innerDrawers);

    if (innerDrawers && innerDrawers.length > 0) {
        innerDrawer = innerDrawers[0].innerDrawer;
        shouldShow = innerDrawers[0].shouldShow;
        innerDrawers.shift();
    }

    return (
        <Drawer
            ...
        >
            <div>
                {sectionOneForm.CreateSection(inputFieldsInjurySection1)}

                {innerDrawer && 
                    innerDrawer(innerDrawers)
                }
                <br/> <br/>
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={shouldShow()} type="primary">Next</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

When I run this, I create an infinite loop.

How can I pass a function to handle when the button is clicked?

Comment: You're seeing an infinite loop because including the parenthesis after shouldShow() executes the function (which I assume is modifying state, causing the component to re-render and then executing shouldShow() again putting you into an infinite loop). Getting rid of the parenthesis ties the onClick to a reference of the function, and it won't be called until the button is clicked.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem, I figured since the accepted answer didn't actually explain why the issue was happening, I'd comment for future reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<Button onClick={shouldShow} type="primary">Next</Button>
```

For further explanation,

```
<Button onClick={shouldShow()} type="primary">Next</Button>
```

will actually invoke the shouldShow function, so the return value will be used as the onClick handler. This is fine if shouldShow itself returns a function, but doesn't work so well if it returns e.g. a string - what does "hello world"() mean?

```
<Button onClick={shouldShow} type="primary">Next</Button>
```

instead sets the function itself as the onClick handler - "when I'm clicked, invoke *this function*, but not until then."

Comment: That worked.  I had tried passing `this._OnClickCloseInjurySection2()` and that caused the same issue.  I didn't try not including the `()` in either passing the function or calling the function.  Thank you!